# Using Puppet to configure hypervisor

Tags: virtual-machines, puppet, virtualbox, vagrant

I am looking to use Puppet to configure a bare-metal host to spawn VMs using Vagrant/VirtualBox, whose configurations will also be managed by Puppet.

I think this can be achieved by:

1. Installing Vagrant/Virtualbox on the host using the below-mentionned Puppet modules.
2. Creating pre-written Vagrantfiles using Puppet.
3. Running a custom service that periodically runs `vagrant up` on a list of Vagrantfile targets.

I can find a ton of resources on how to provision VMs using Vagrant/Virtualbox and configuring them using Puppet, but little on how to configure the host that is serving as a hypervisor using Puppet other than Puppet modules for installing [Vagrant](https://forge.puppet.com/modules?q=vagrant) and [Virtualbox](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppet/virtualbox), respectively.  This makes me doubt whether I am approaching the problem correctly - and whether I overlooked a more obvious implementation.

What do you think?

Thanks!

Nicolas

Comment: The obvious problem is trying to use VirtualBox/Vagrant.

Comment: Are you proposing to use something like proxmox, Hyper-V, VMware, ESXi instead?